# How to trigger a hot backup when using a mysql database with perfino 3.0?

Tags: perfino

After recent H2 database corruption I'm considering migrating to mysql. My only concern is how to create a hot backup in case that this is not supported out-of-the-box.

According to the [release notes](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/perfino/whatsnew3.html):

> You can now perform **hot backups of the database** with the REST API. By calling the `/triggerBackup` URL, a directory named "backup" is created in the data directory that can be renamed to "db" when you need to restore the backup.

I have tested it and it works for the internal H2 database (perfino 3.0.1+ required). But when using mysql database, no `backup` directory is created and I get the following log:

```
INFO  [backup-thread-1] server: Backup requested
WARN  [backup-thread-1] server: External database: only call site data is backed up
INFO  [backup-thread-1] server: Backup succeed
```

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot use the backup trigger in the REST API, you can use mysqldump to get a backup from a live MySQL database.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, `mysqldump` isn't appropriate for online-backups of MyISAM tables (I'm pretty sure that perfino has good reasons to use MyISAM instead other engine). But your suggestion made me revisit this issue and I'm now using a two passes rsync + `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` script. I'll post the script if time proves it robust.

Comment: I have asked around and experience seems to discourage the use of such a script. We have had some problems in the past with corrupted backups generated this way. Furthermore, the time slot during which the database is blocked is significant (few minutes for 30-50 GB DBs).

Comment: What is worse, I'm currently loosing data. See my [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42141121/413020)