# How to configure mysql for perfino?

Tags: perfino

After a H2 database corruption, I'm considering migrating to mysql. But in my first attempt, I'm loosing lots of data (with H2 it was a nice continuous curve):

[image: perfino loosing data]

I could find the following quote in the `perfino.properties`:

> Please note that it is possible to configure MySQL in such a way that it
>   will not work with the perfino connection pool, including (but not
>   limited to) setting low values for max_allowed_packet or max_connections.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation about mysql recommended configuration. I have fiddled a bit with `my.cnf` but either I have yet to find the optimal configuration, or mysql is not appropriate as persistence solution for perfino.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

---

#### Edit

I found remarkable the difference in the telemetry "*JDBC Average Statement Execution Time*" for Perfino:

- Using H2: about 25 us.
- Using MySQL: about 5 ms.

The corresponding comparison:

[image: Perfino H2 vs MySQL]

I'm attaching another screenshot, just to make the problem more evident:
[image: perfino transactions with mysql]

Comment: Have a look at the error log in perfino, it should show relevant exceptions. If mysql is configured correctly, it definitely works.

Comment: That'd have also been my guess. Unfortunately, the logs doesn't show anything relevant. If needed, I could paste/link them here, but I find them completely uninteresting.

Comment: And to clarify things, I have repeated the tests assigning perfino more hardware resources, but this hasn't helped either. (The 'mysql cpu' idles now more than 20% of the time, and the 'java cpu' more than 45%. There are two more cpus that idle 100% of the time.)

Comment: Now that I've already given up, have found the infamous `log4j.properties`. I could probably tune it to log more info, but as I said, it has already taken too much time.